# How can I change locale at reverseGeocoding?

Tags: swift, localization, reverse-geocoding

I'd like to display address by Japanese.
I understand that I need to set Locale to "preferredLocale" of "reverseGeocodeLocation()". So I try this.

```
let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: Locale.init(identifier: "ja_JP"), completionHandler: { (placemark, error) -> Void in
```

But it's not working.
And I set "Japan" at "Localization native development region" in "Info.plist". But it's not working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your target try to modify `Application Language` and `Application Region` inside your `Edit Scheme`-> `Options`

[image]